# Intellij IDEA settings for jooq

Tags: jooq

Is there a plugin, or what are your settings for formatting jooq methods? Curious to know if you have any rules that you could share). Below is an example

```
private Field<Set<Role>> getRolesSelect() {
    return multiset(
            select(USER_ROLE.AUTHORITY_ID.as(ROLE.ID))
                .from(USER_ROLE)
            .where(USER_ROLE.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))
        ).as("roles")
        .convertFrom(f -> f.intoSet(roleMapper));
}
```

or just

```
private Field<Set<Role>> getRolesSelect() {
    return multiset(
            select(USER_ROLE.AUTHORITY_ID.as(ROLE.ID))
                .from(USER_ROLE)
                .where(USER_ROLE.USER_ID.eq(USER.ID))).as("roles")
        .convertFrom(f -> f.intoSet(roleMapper));
}
```

try to find out jooq convention

Comment: There isn't a jOOQ convention that I'm aware of. You'd follow the convention in your codebase. For example, we align chained method calls, wrap and indent long chains, etc.